# Kubernetes timeout

Tags: kubernetes

I can't for the life of me get this to connect.

It is a golang application using Kubernetes.
The docker file runs just fine, the pod launches but the connection times out.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  ark-service
  namespace: ark
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30008
  selector:
    app: ark-api
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ark-backend
  namespace: ark
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ark-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ark-api
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: ark-api-container
          image: xxx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 8080
```

I am able to boot the docker container just fine and it runs.

Turns out the container gets terminated and I have no idea why.

Comment: Which port are you trying to connect?

Comment: the api in golang runs on 8080

Comment: The nodeport in on 30008.

Comment: ok so that has to reflect what the container is listening to?

Comment: should I switch to something else because doesn't nodeport (limited search, have to run on 30000-32767)

Comment: No. The container is listening on 8080. There is a nodeport service on 30008 forwarding to that 8080. So any external connection on any one of the nodes on port 30008 will be forwarded to the container's 8080 port. Try connecting to 30008. That is your external port. The container's port is only open to the k8s pod network.

Comment: ah see I tried that :) I have tried every port listed just to cover my basis. everything results in a timeout.

Comment: are you using any ingress or is it on local machine?

Comment: local machine first :) I wanted to understand how to boot locally before moving to the cloud.

Comment: I had a similar situation and increasing pod size helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could check wheather the port 8080 is listening inside the container 
   `kubectl exec -it <pod_namen> -n <namespace>  -- netstat -ntpl` 
   if there is no netstat command in the container, you could try to build a base image with it.
2. Check whether the port 30080 is listening on the node. Run the following command on the node 
   `netstat -ntpl | grep 30080` 
   Also you could try not to specify the node port in the service yaml, let the kubernetes to choose the nodeport for you. That could avoid to specify the port which is already using in your node.

Comment: will try tonight.

Comment: it just hangs. this is interesting tech, but regular containers are much easier :(

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ark-service
  namespace: ark
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: ark-api
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Try using clusterIP instead of nodeport, if you are using any kind of Ingress then you have to create rules in your ingress config so It can expose your service to the outside web via your load balancer.

Comment: Other than this, I'd like to know what port your docker container is exposing and is it the same port as your `ark-api` config is exposing. Sorry but I haven't worked much with nodeport so kinda rusty with that.

Comment: this is all localhost on Mac OS X m1 chip.

Comment: does it being a "deployment" vs a "pod" have anything to do with it?

Comment: no, I don't think so!

Comment: changing from nodeport to clusterIP didn't work for you either?

Comment: send me your discord, I'd love to explore this problem!

Comment: don't use discord but I can set one up. let me try clusterIP

Comment: so did it work for you or nah?

Comment: no it didn't I had to delete the service and use just deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the service and used port forwarding and was able to boot everything. I'll have to circle back to the service to try and figure it out.